# Joomla Manifest XML works in XAMPP but doesn't work in Hosting

Tags: joomla-4.x, manifest

I created a template for Joomla 4x, it works well in XAMPP, but doesn't work well in my Hosting, it is Installed successfully in my hosting but I got an Error when I try to access the template configuration, when I try to click the SYSTEM -> SITE TEMPLATE STYLES -> THE SAID TEMPLATE, I got an

> Error loading form file

message.

this is my MANIFEST:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<extension type="template" client="site">
    <name>masterlapak_template</name>
    <creationDate>2023-01-27</creationDate>
    <author>dhany</author>
    <authorEmail>dhanyfling@gmail.com</authorEmail>
    <authorUrl>masterlapak.com</authorUrl>
    <copyright>Master Graphic</copyright>
    <license>GNU/GPL</license>
    <version>1.0.2</version>
    <description>masterlapak template</description>
    <inheritable>1</inheritable>
    
    <files>
        <filename>index.php</filename>
        <filename>index1.php</filename>
        <filename>templatedetails.xml</filename>
        <folder>images</folder> 
        <folder>my_image</folder>
        <folder>script</folder>         
    </files>
    <positions>     
        <position>head</position>
        <position>menu</position>
        <position>main-top</position>   
        <position>main-bottom</position>        
        <position>myWhatsapp</position>        
        <position>myFacebook</position>
        <position>myMap</position>
    </positions>
    
    <config>
        <fields name="params">                            
            <fieldset name="mybodyfont" label="Body google font">
                <field name="mybodyfontname" label="Font Name" type="text" description="Nama Google Font"/>                
                <field name="mybodyfontcategory" type="list" default="sans-serif" required="true" label="Body Font Category" description="Jenis Category yang anda pilih pada saat memilih google font">
                      <option value="serif">serif</option>
                      <option value="sans-serif">sans-serif</option>
                      <option value="cursive">display</option>
                      <option value="cursive">hand writing</option>
                      <option value="monospace">monospace</option>
                </field>
                <field name="mybodyfontsize" type="range" default="13" label="Ukuran huruf" description="dari 0 - 100" min="0" max="100" step="1" />
                <field name="mylogo" label="logo" type="accessiblemedia" />                
            </fieldset>               
        </fields>
    </config>
</extension>
```

I tried to find where is the Error but couldn't find one, it is tested in XAMPP and doesn't generate any Error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that the templatedetails.xml file does exist in your hosting directory.

If your local XAMPP is on a Windows machine then you probably have an upper vs lower case character issue which is pretty common when developing on Windows and installing on a Unix based hosting accounts. On Windows the lowercase and uppercase characters are treated as interchangeable however this is not the case when you get to your hosting environment where an 'A' is not treated the same as an 'a'.

Based on your description I would be looking at the case of the the template file name mentioned here.

```
<filename>templatedetails.xml</filename>
```

The actual file names needs to be `templatedetails.xml` and not `templateDetails.xml` or `Templatedetails.xml` etc.

The same issue of upper/lowercase characters could be involved in the contents of your templatedetails.xml preventing it from loading correctly.

Turn on Debug and Error Reporting and you might receive more useful diagnostics that might be more specific as to what the issue is.